# OAuth2 token introspection for each service request?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I've implemented a Spring based REST API (resource server) that uses the OAuth2 authorization code flow. The receives an opaque access token from the client and validated this token through a custom token introspector.

For each HTTP request, the resource server has to verify the provided access token through an additional HTTP call to the token introspection service.

Is there a way, to cache the token so that the resource server don't have to send a token verification request each time?

Can [HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/context/HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java) be used for that purpose?

Here'y my configuration:

```
 @Configuration
 public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       
        http.authorizeRequests(authz -> authz.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/foos/**")
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated())
            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 ->
                 oauth2.opaqueToken.introspector(myIntrospector)
        );
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resource servers are generally configured stateless (without sessions).

In the conf you expose, sessions are not disabled, but this doesn't mean that it is used to build the requests security context. What is used is the token introspector.

So if there should be some caching, it could be inside this introspector (cache the introspection response for given token strings). But this caching would contradict the most frequent motivation for introspection: validate for each request that the session was not closed on the authorization server. This has an important performance impact and is of use mainly when you can't trust client(s) to properly delete tokens when a user session is terminated on the authorization server.

As a conclusion, if performance is important, use only [OAuth2 clients on your servers](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390) which you can trust to delete tokens when user logs out (`spring-cloud-gateway` is a good candidate when [configured with `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`, `oauth2Login` and `TokenRelay=` filter](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff)), have your authorization server issue JWT access tokens, and configure your resource server(s) with a JWT decoder. With this pattern, the access tokens are "cached" in session on the OAuth2 client and requests are authorized with:

- session (cookie) between the remote front-ends and the OAuth2 client on your server (most probably a gateway)
- JWTs between the OAuth2 client and the resource servers (as well as within inter resource servers communications)

Answer (score 1):

Opaque access tokens are often used as a privacy preserving best practice, to avoid revealing confidential information (easily readable in JWTs) to internet clients. Yet you don't want to hammer the authorization server (a critical conponent) on every API request.

One elegant way to deal with introspection and caching is to host an API gateway in front of APIs and do the introspection in a `gateway plugin`, along with result caching. Alternatively you can do this in APIs, though that is less optimal, especially when multiple APIs call each other.

**COMBINING OPAQUE TOKENS AND JWTs**

The gateway can send an introspection request and ideally use an `accept: application/jwt` header, so that the introspection response is a JWT access token that can be forwarded to APIs. See this [proposed standard](https://www.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-oauth-jwt-introspection-response-12.html) which some authorization servers support.

At Curity, where I work, we call this the `phantom token pattern`. The advantage of the JWT response is to maintain a credential for requests inside the cluster. This provides a more complete `zero trust` API security solution, since the JWT can also be forwarded to upstream APIs.

Comment: In my opinion, and more importantly in [Spring security teams one](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390), **"internet clients" should not be OAuth2 clients**. OAuth2 clients should be on servers you trust (requests from the internet to those clients being authorized with sessions). If the tokens don't leave your servers, you don't really care if the information it contains can be read from it...

Comment: More generally different types of clients use different best practices. We recommend web clients use SameSite cookies which can contain opaque tokens. Mobile clients follow RFC8252 with opaque tokens, and B2B clients follow RFC8705 with opaque tokens. The gateway can handle these differences, with API security then based on JWTs. An overview of our recommendations [here](https://curity.io/resources/learn/implementing-zero-trust-apis/).

Comment: In addition to `SameSite`, the cookies can be `HttpOnly` to hide it from Javascript code. I don't see the point to have this cookie set with an opaque token issued by the authorization server and then introspected for a JWT. The `spring-cloud-gateway` way of keeping tokens in session and setting the session cookie with UUID is much more efficient.

Comment: Also, if at [step 5 of RFC8252](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8252#section-4.1), the mobile app presents the authorization code to the gateway instead of the authorization server token endpoint, then it is possible to have the tokens delivered to the gateway instead of the mobile app, and to keep the tokens on the servers only: tokens are stored in session on the gateway (a session on associated with the mobile app user agent which presented the authorization code). This is safer than sending tokens to mobile apps which store it with random safety...

Comment: And more importantly, this is also safer than using a "public" client as required by RFC8252: mobile apps can't keep a secret to call the token endpoint (the gateway can). This also enables to set some network level protection for the token endpoint (only the gateway will call it).

Comment: Well your mobile session ID is acting as an opaque token / API credential and might be exploited for longer than a short lived opaque access token if stolen. If you were to shorten its lifetime and implement a renewal mechanism, it would look like that of the public client you describe.

Comment: A web BFF reduces the impact of cross site scripting exploits. For a mobile BFF this is not usually an objective. Native keystore capabilities can improve security in some cases, though this is often not practical, leading to the limitations you describe.